# rails finding previous and next records alphabetically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On a user show screen, I need to put links to the previous and next user, with the links taking me to the next or previous user in alphabetical order by last name, within an account.

I should probably explain that...

Our users are grouped by account, with an account_id on each user. When someone logs into their account and looks at a user, they need to be able to click a button and go to the next user ordered by a field on the user, last_name

So I'm displaying it on the view with

```
= @user.next_employee.last_name.upcase
```

I then went to the employee model and put a placeholder in place like

```
def next_user
  User.find(100)
end
```

That was everything hooked up, but then I obviously need to turn the instance method into something useful. So I did a bit of research and found this...

```
  def next_user
    self.class.first(:conditions => ["last_name > ?", last_name], :order => "last_name desc")
  end
```

From my limited understanding, this seems to do what I want woth the exception of limiting it by account. However, when my test user has a surname of "Roberts" the record returned has a last_name of "wong", which suggests it's getting the first record it finds order by last_name descending in the database, which I don't understand.

Even more strangely, when I look at the console, the SQL being run at that time is

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (users.deleted_at IS NULL) AND (last_name > 'Richards') ORDER BY first_name, last_name asc LIMIT 1
```

not sure where the "first_name" thing is creeping in...

EDIT: thats down to

```
default_scope order(:first_name)
```

on the user model.

Where am I going wrong.

EDIT2: Apologies to all readers. I've cracked it.

Just needed to add "unscoped" to ensure the default scope is ignored. Now the following code works.

```
  def next_user
    self.class.unscoped.first(:conditions => ["last_name > ?", last_name], :order => "last_name desc")
  end
```

The final stage is to work out how to limit it to a specific account. I'm nervous about passing in the account_id as a parameter as someone could presumably just change this on the page and pass in another account_id, and current_account is not available in the model.

And this works in the end...

```
User.unscoped.where(:account_id => self.account_id).first(:conditions => ["last_name > ?", last_name], :order => "last_name asc").account_id
```

Now I just need to tidy things up a bit for the first and last record and job done. Sorry to bother you all!

Comment: I think you are trying to implement pagination. Take a look at a gem like [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate).

Comment: TBH I'm trying to learn Ruby and I'm finding the more gems I install the less I understand!

Answer (score 0):

You found it yourself it seems. You need to remove the `default_scope` that you've supplied. You can do this by unscoping the model with [`unscoped`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class):

`self.class.unscoped.where('last_name > ?', last_name).order('last_name DESC')`

Comment: lol, yes you're right, sorry was writing up my reply when you answered!